# What regex could be used to match a substring no matter the order?

Tags: regex, substring

I want to match a substring no matter the order in which I use it. For example:

> 82toto12a
>   MyProject888
>   TeamCitySupermarket897

I have this regex that matches it

```
.*?toto.*?12
```

But I'm creating the regex dynamically so I could end up having:

```
.*?12.*?toto
```

And of course that does not work. I have a search box that translates to regex so a user could enter : "12 and toto" and that would translate to the above regex that of course does not work.

To match any of the strings about, the user might enter:

> MyProject and 888
>   or
>   888 and MyProject

Both those user string would end up being translated to regex as:

```
.*?MyProject.*?888
.*?888.*?MyProject
```

And of course the second regex would not match anything...

What would be the test way to have a match of each word the user enters?

Comment: Can you supply more test-cases?

Comment: I would check each separately. That's easier to maintain and extend, and probably more readable than a giant regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds for your matches:

```
\b(?=\w*toto)(?=\w*12)\w+
```

OR:

```
\b(?=\w*12)(?=\w*toto)\w+
```

both will match your input: `82toto12a`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO5hP8/1)